# REQUEST_FILENAME without extension in RewriteCond

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there any mode_rewrite variable like {REQUEST_FILENAME} but without the file extension?

The following works but I need to change my image naming:

```
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp -f
        RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.webp [NC,L]
```

But now i need to change my image naming from: "image.jpg.webp" to "image_jpg.webp".
I need help with the new RewriteCond and RewriteRule in order to rewrite "image.jpg" to "image_jpg.webp" if the webp image exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just capture value in `RewriteRule` and use it in `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1%2_%3.webp -f
RewriteRule ^ %1%2_%3.webp [L]
```

Comment: I dont know why but it does not work for me. My image.jpg is not available as image_jpg.webp (image not found).

Comment: Yes example.com/image_jpg.webp works. Sorry, there is no "image not found" message i just get the jpg image served and not the webp image.

Comment: ok, that might be due to your browser cache. Can you test in a new browser to test after completely clearing browser cache.

Comment: I already did, no luck. I think the problem is that %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} points to the root and not to the location where the images are located: example.com/folder/image_jpg.webp or example.com/folder/folder2/image_jpg.webp etc. The jpg and webp image are always in the same folder and location.

Comment: Thank you that might work but looks really complicated. Would it be more easy if I change my naming to "image.jpg" and "image.webp" without the ext?

Comment: The problem is NGINX server do not accept more than 1 file extension. Thats why I need to change something and image.jpg.webp wont work.

Comment: You never mentioned `NGINX` anywhere and half of the htaccess anyway won't work in `NGINX`.

Comment: Because of NGINX I need to change my naming but the rules have nothing to do with NGINX thats right.